# PHP: PDO not connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I have a problem I think. My PHP PDO code didn't work at all. I've followed everything maybe in the manual but it seem doesn't work, it just returning a blank page and in my database there are no data at all. Below are my codes for php and I am using Xampp. What i've done wrong?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    try{
        $dbh = new PDO ("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=test", $username, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $create_params_query = "INSERT INTO testingdb (name, email, message)
        VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["email"]."', '".$_POST["message"]."')";

        if($dbh->query($sqlite)){
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('You're data has been sent. Thank you!');</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Sorry, you're data not being sent. Please try again.');</script>";
        }

    }catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
$dbh = null;

?>
```

Comment: Have you got any error??

Comment: what error it is showing?

Comment: Try replacing `$dbname=test` with `dbname=test`

Comment: a *blank page* means something is broken. Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: Change `$dbh->query($sqlite)` to `$dbh->query($create_params_query)`

Comment: ShafiqqAziz please check the answer and if it worked then mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks.

Comment: People are not interested in checking answers and telling status along with marking and up-vote. Wastage of time and effort. deleting my answer.

Comment: Sorry guys for the late respond, kinda busy lately.. I'll try it today

Comment: Sorry guys,, none of them working,..

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I've added that line of code,, there are no error at all..

Comment: @Saty changed that line also not working

Comment: @Rainner still noting happened

Comment: Please show your error message !!

Comment: @Saty no error at all,, just a blank page

Comment: Use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to check error. Write this at top of your page

Comment: @Saty why I put the error code but still not getting error? I am putting it on the top of the page